# Is every left primitive ring a division ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, division-ring

I was solving some exercises about left primitive rings but the "proof" I found for them doesn't use all the assumptions, so I wanted to know if there are left primitive rings wich are not division rings. The exercises were "Let $R$ be a left primitive ring, if either for all $a,b \in R$,  $a(ab-ba) = (ab-ba)a$ or $1+a^2$ is always a unit then $R$ is a division ring."

I have a "proof" (I'm pretty sure it is wrong because it solves both these exercises at the same time), it goes as follows:

(1) If $R$ is a left primitive ring then for all $\forall a \neq 0 \in R,\exists b \in R, ba = 1$.

Proof of (1): Since $R$ is a left primitive ring there exists a simple module $S$ such that $ann_R(S) = \{0\}$. If $a \neq 0 \in R$ then $a \notin ann_R(S) \implies \exists v \in S, av \neq 0$. Since $av \neq 0$ and $S$ is simple, $R(av) = S$. This in particular implies that $\exists b \in R, b(av) = v$, wich in turn implies $b(av) - v = 0 \iff (ba - 1)v = 0$ and since $ann_R(S) = \{0\}$, $ba -1 = 0 \implies ba  = 1.$

Now it is only necessary to check that $b$ is also a right inverse of $a$ but we have that

$$
ab = a\cdot1\cdot b = a \cdot(ba) \cdot b = ab(ab) \implies b = b(ab) \implies 1 = ab
$$

where the implications follow from $a,b \neq 0$ and therefore both have a left inverse.

Where is the mistake in my proof ? Assuming it is wrong what are some examples of left primitive rings which are not division rings?

Comment: [DaRT query for left-primitive rings which are not division rings](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=74l&L=2).

Comment: Every simple ring is primitive (the annihilator of any simple module would have to be zero!). Surely you believe simple rings exist other than division rings. At least, if you've heard of matrix rings over fields you should have...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flaw in your argument is that $(ba-1)v=0$ implies $ba-1=0$. For this to work, you would have to have that $ba-1$ annihilates *all* of $S$, but here you only know that it annihilates $v$.

Take a field $k$ and $R=M_2(k)$ the ring of $2\times 2$ matricies. Then $k^2$ is a faithful simple $R$-module. Indeed, if $(0)\subsetneq M\subseteq k^2$ is a non-trivial submodule of $k^2$, let $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}\in M\setminus\{0\}$. Then multiplying on the right by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ resp. $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, we obtain that $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\in M$ resp. $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ b\end{pmatrix}\in M$. By scaling, and as at least one of $a,b$ is non-zero, we obtain that either $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\in M$ or $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\in M$ is in $M$. So multiplying on the left by $\begin{pmatrix} x & x \\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$, we obtain that $M$ contains all of $k^2$, i.e. $M=k^2$. So $k^2$ is a simple $R$-module.

Furthermore, $k^2$ is faithful because if $A\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=0$, then $A=0$.

Finally, $R$ is not a division ring, because $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ doesn't admit a left nor a right inverse.

Comment: Funny, the question was posed an hour ago, and just now we posted almost exactly the same answers. I like your example better though!

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Haha funny coincidence indeed! And +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is the last implication, concluding that $ba-1=0$. Indeed, you know that $(ba-1)v=0$, but this does not hold for all $v$, but just the one $v$ you picked, and the annihilator requires this equality to hold for all $v$.

I am pretty sure most matrix rings would be left primitive rings that are not division rings. To give you a concrete example, let $R=M_2(\mathbb{R})$. I will be using the equivalent criterion of being left primitive: the ring has a maximal left ideal containing no two-sided ideal.
Look at the maximal left $R$-ideal
$$I =\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\
b & 0  
\end{pmatrix} \mid a\in\mathbb{R}\rbrace.$$
But
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\
b & 0  
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0  
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\
0 & b  
\end{pmatrix},$$
Showing that no non-zero subset of $I$ is a right ideal. This concludes the example.

Comment: *I am pretty sure most matrix rings would be left primitive rings* indeed, every full matrix ring over a left primitive ring is left primitive.